# Alternative to PDE target platform

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde, target-platform

We have a RCP e4 application and we have a target definition file within our project structure which defines our target platform.
Our problem is now that every time when we need to add a new software site to our target platform definition it crashes and looks like this:

[image]

To resolve this problem we have to completely select all our categories within the software sites again ... Till now this wasn't a big hazard because we had only a few update sites and every developer knew which categories have to be selected, but now that our target platform becomes larger everyday it really gets complicated and I wondered if there is an alternative way of defining our target platform within eclipse?

Or does anyone actually know why there always comes this annoying failure that PDE unable to locate installable unit?

The best way would be to have some external server software which collects all the necessary plug-ins, downloads them to a local p2 repository and then we just reference it from our eclipse target platform configuration. Through this we wouldn't need to change our target definition file of our eclipse project anymore and that would eventually resolve this bug ...

I really would appreciate every help or pointers I could possibly get. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Personally I just use directories containing the plugins I want to use rather than software sites. I have not run in to problems like this using this system.

Comment: @greg-449 Hmm ok but how do you download all this software sites? We need them as P2 sites because we are using Tycho and it only accepts P2 as a target platform definition ...

Comment: I don't use tycho so I can't help

Comment: Have you tried using the Reload button on the target platform preference page rather than reselecting all the content?  In 4.5 the target editor will have a reload button in it as well.

Comment: @CWindatt Yeah you are right this seems to resolve the problem but takes ages because it seems to download everything again ...

Comment: It will have to contact the remote repository and get the metadata, but it shouldn't have to download all of the artifacts (unless something new is required according to p2).  If some IU is not available at the repository, the operation should quit early and never download any artifacts.  Then on reload if it does find all the IUs required it would perform the download then.  You can also look at turning off 'include required software' setting in the target.  Then the whole operation won't fail because one IU is missing.

Comment: This question is not well suited for stackoverflow because it is open-ended: You already have a solution but you are looking for a better one. There are no objectively correct answers for this requirement - SO questions should have "correct" answers.